# How to add Column and Row header while appending data into CSV file using C#

Tags: c#, export-to-csv

I'm trying to insert data into CSV file using C# code. With the code I pasted below, I am able to add column header to the CSV file. But I need to add both column and row header in the CSV file for better readability. Please help me on this.

**C# Code**

```
string newFileName = "C:\\AlertReportTill_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") + ".csv";
string AlertDetails = fromDate + "," + toDate + "," + Column1's Value + "," + Column2's Value + ","
        + Column3's Value + "," + Environment.NewLine;

if (!System.IO.File.Exists(newFileName))
        {
            string AlertHeader = "Weekly Report" + Environment.NewLine + "From Date" + "," + "To Date" + "," +
                                 "ColumnHeader1" + "," + "ColumnHeader2" + "," +
                                 "ColumnHeader3" + "," + Environment.NewLine;

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(newFileName, AlertHeader);
        } //End of If Statement

System.IO.File.AppendAllText(newFileName, AlertDetails);
```

For better clarity, I have added an image below to help you understand my question. It would be very helpful if someone can sort this out for me. Thanks in advance.

[image: ExpectedOutput]

Comment: You need to add the code.

Comment: The row header you just need to add to the beginning of each row the new column with a space : string row = reader.ReadLine();  row = "New Data," + row;

Comment: @mortb: I have added the code on top please take a look at it! I am in need of adding three row headers also into my CSV file.

Comment: @jdweng: I'm unable to understand what you explained, could you please help in detail?

Comment: Deepak619: What do you mean by a Row Header?

Comment: Is a row header just an extra column?

Comment: From your example I see it is essentially an extra column.

Comment: It seems you could just add an empty header which would be "," to the `AlertHeader` string and an value "RowHeaderX," to the `AlertDetails`. If you want to have a "row number" on your RowHeader, you need to read the last line (if any) and add one to the last RowHeader row number

Comment: @codeulike I have added a JPEG for a better understanding. Please view that and help if I can do that using the code.

Comment: @mortb: I'm afraid I'm not looking for the row number, instead I want to classify records in the CSV file. Like, Students Passed, Students Failed  will be Column headers. Class 5-A, Class 5-B will be Row headers.

Comment: From what I see in the image, you just need to add a column with no text or "row header" and add the value for the row header like all the other data.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication104
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string oldFileName = "C:\\AlertReportTill.csv";
            string newFileName = string.Format("C:\\AlertReportTill_{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss"));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(oldFileName);
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(newFileName))
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(newFileName);
                writer.WriteLine("Weekly Report");


                string AlertHeader = string.Join(",", new string[] 
                   {"",
                    "ColumnHeader1", "ColumnHeader2", "ColumnHeader3"
                   });
                writer.WriteLine(AlertHeader);

                string line = "";
                int RowCount = 0;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    List<string> AlertDetails = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();
                    AlertDetails.Insert(0, "RowHeader" + ++RowCount);

                    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", AlertDetails));
                }

                reader.Close();
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();

            } //End of If Statement

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry @jdweng! I'm afraid this didn't help! I'm in need of adding row header as in the JPEG! Thanks for your effort.

Comment: I updated code.  I originally used you sample code where you added a from and to data to each row.  New code now matches you sample output.  Make sure you delete the old file because new file will not be written if it matches the old file.